# Angular2 preventDefault not working

Tags: angular

I need to disable press F5 button for disable reload page but it not working

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean { 
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.key);
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: do you gen any output in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.keyCode == 116) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely while testing it you see that (at least in chrome) F5 Keydown triggers the reload. So when you check Keyup it is already too late.

Here a pure JavaScript Version which I tested on the Google-Chrome Console:

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    //If the key that was pressed down is F5 (Key Code : 116), Ignore it
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) {
         e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.